# How to install C# in Mac OSX

Tags: c#, macos

can somebody pls tell me how to install C# in Mac OSX 10.6?

Comment: Umm, you don't. C# is just a language.

Comment: Do you mean the .Net framework, or do you actually want to write C# programs?

Comment: Just because you generally can't doesn't mean johan deserves to be voted down for wanting to.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can try something like [Mono](http://www.mono-project.com/Mono:OSX).

Comment: Or, for specifically Mac apps, MonoMac.

Answer (score 0):

Since Visual Studio 2017, Microsoft now offers support for Mac OS. Developers can get the community edition for free which comes with the option to install C# and the .NET framework. However, the .NET framework appears to be limited at this time of writing to version 2.1 on Mac OS.

Aside, I understand this version also includes support for iOS, Android, and Unity.

... not to be confused with the lightweight Visual Studio Code.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Homebrew](https://brew.sh/) to install the latest version of .NET using the [`dotnet`](https://formulae.brew.sh/cask/dotnet) cask:

```sh
brew install --cask dotnet
```

See https://stackoverflow.com/a/57880964/1110395 for installing specific versions with Homebrew.

Manual installers can be downloaded from https://dotnet.microsoft.com/download