# Multiple versions of .Net Core on Macos with brew

Tags: macos, .net-core, homebrew

I have been searching for a while but I haven't found anything accurate in 2019 about that how can I have multiple versions from .Net Core on Mac. My use case is that, I use .Net Core 2.2 for active development, and I'd like to play with .Net Core 3 and the goodness it has now like Razor Components and Blazor stuff.

I found articles about how .Net Core multiple version can live on the same system on Windows, which is awesome. But, Mac is not Windows (luckily, and unfortunately), and I'd like to use brew as package manager which is dealing with managing versions instead of me. If it is possible, I don't want to move out form brew zone.

I haven't found information about that how brew can help me out, rather it throws an error message saying that it will overwrite dotnet command.

```
mbp2017 ➜  ~ brew search dotnet
==> Casks
dotnet                                      dotnet-preview                              dotnet-sdk ✔                                dotnet-sdk-preview
mbp2017 ➜  ~ dotnet --info
.NET Core SDK (reflecting any global.json):
 Version:   2.2.105
 Commit:    7cecb35b92

Runtime Environment:
 OS Name:     Mac OS X
 OS Version:  10.14
 OS Platform: Darwin
 RID:         osx.10.14-x64
 Base Path:   /usr/local/share/dotnet/sdk/2.2.105/

Host (useful for support):
  Version: 2.2.3
  Commit:  6b8ad509b6

.NET Core SDKs installed:
  2.2.105 [/usr/local/share/dotnet/sdk]

.NET Core runtimes installed:
  Microsoft.AspNetCore.All 2.2.3 [/usr/local/share/dotnet/shared/Microsoft.AspNetCore.All]
  Microsoft.AspNetCore.App 2.2.3 [/usr/local/share/dotnet/shared/Microsoft.AspNetCore.App]
  Microsoft.NETCore.App 2.2.3 [/usr/local/share/dotnet/shared/Microsoft.NETCore.App]

To install additional .NET Core runtimes or SDKs:
  https://aka.ms/dotnet-download
mbp2017 ➜  ~ brew cask install dotnet-sdk-preview
Error: Cask 'dotnet-sdk-preview' conflicts with 'dotnet-sdk'.
➜  ~ dotnet --list-sdks
2.2.105 [/usr/local/share/dotnet/sdk]
```

I found articles about DNVM, but turned out that it was something around .Net Core 1.x, since then seems not usable.

How is possible to have multiple versions from .Net Core for example using brew? If brew can't do this, then what is the suggested way?

Comment: There shouldn't be any problems installing multiple versions. Try installing .NET Core 3 and then run `dotnet --list-sdk` (or something like that, use `dotnet` to find out). If you don't see both 3 and 2.2, you should be able to just uninstall 3

Comment: What's the exact message when "[brew] throws an error message saying that it will overwrite dotnet command."?

Comment: @LexLi I read that article and it is Win specific, and as I mentioned Macos package manager fails. I don't know package manager can't or won't do the package management for me or I have to do it myself.

Comment: @CamiloTerevinto I updated my question, it already includes these details.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It seems brew cannot help, or at least, I haven't find a solution. However, just downloading and installing packages from .Net Core websites solves the problem. Installing both version SDKS, you will have both.

```
➜  ~ dotnet --info
.NET Core SDK (reflecting any global.json):
 Version:   3.0.100-preview3-010431
 Commit:    d72abce213

Runtime Environment:
 OS Name:     Mac OS X
 OS Version:  10.14
 OS Platform: Darwin
 RID:         osx.10.14-x64
 Base Path:   /usr/local/share/dotnet/sdk/3.0.100-preview3-010431/

Host (useful for support):
  Version: 3.0.0-preview3-27503-5
  Commit:  3844df9537

.NET Core SDKs installed:
  2.2.105 [/usr/local/share/dotnet/sdk]
  3.0.100-preview3-010431 [/usr/local/share/dotnet/sdk]

.NET Core runtimes installed:
  Microsoft.AspNetCore.All 2.2.3 [/usr/local/share/dotnet/shared/Microsoft.AspNetCore.All]
  Microsoft.AspNetCore.App 2.2.3 [/usr/local/share/dotnet/shared/Microsoft.AspNetCore.App]
  Microsoft.AspNetCore.App 3.0.0-preview3-19153-02 [/usr/local/share/dotnet/shared/Microsoft.AspNetCore.App]
  Microsoft.NETCore.App 2.2.3 [/usr/local/share/dotnet/shared/Microsoft.NETCore.App]
  Microsoft.NETCore.App 3.0.0-preview3-27503-5 [/usr/local/share/dotnet/shared/Microsoft.NETCore.App]

To install additional .NET Core runtimes or SDKs:
  https://aka.ms/dotnet-download
```

Comment: Installing `dotnet` and `dotnet@6` with brew then adding `export PATH="/usr/local/share/dotnet:$PATH"` to dotfile also works

Answer (score 92):

A little late to the party but you can now do this with the `dotnet-sdk-versions` tap.

You can find it here: https://github.com/isen-ng/homebrew-dotnet-sdk-versions

```
brew tap isen-ng/dotnet-sdk-versions
brew install --cask dotnet-sdk2-2-100

dotnet --list-sdks
```

Disclaimer: I wrote the tap 2 days ago

Comment: Looks promising, but running `brew cask install dotnet-sdk-2.2.400` returns a "Cask 'dotnet-sdk-2.2.400' conflicts with 'dotnet-sdk'" error for me.

Comment: That is expected. The latest version provided by the official cask and the corresponding version of my cask will conflict. E.g. you cannot install 2 copies of 2.2.402 on the same machine.

Comment: You can, however, install any other version without conflict.

Comment: Right, I was looking at the [version table](https://github.com/isen-ng/homebrew-dotnet-sdk-versions#versions) and thought that `dotnet-sdk-2.2.400` maps to SDK 2.2.401 (as opposed to 2.2.402).  Regardless, your tap is a great addition.

Comment: Ahh, you're right. I just checked the official casks and I found that they have added 3.0.100 to the official as well IFF your os is > sierra ... I'll need to update the tap with all the new stuff. Thanks for the compliments!

Comment: Small update.  I got this error "Error: Calling brew cask install is disabled! Use brew install [--cask] instead"...but as it says, this works : "brew install --cask  dotnet-sdk3-1-400"       Thanks Isen!!!

Answer (score 8):

Step-1: Open terminal

Step-2: brew install dotnet

Note: You can use a specific version below the link
https://github.com/isen-ng/homebrew-dotnet-sdk-versions

Step-3: vi .zshrc

Step-4: export PATH="/usr/local/share/dotnet:$PATH"

Step-5: Press Esc key

Step-6: :wq + Enter key

Step-7: source .zshrc

Step-8: dotnet --info [for checking purpose]

Answer (score 4):

As an alternative solution for people who came here from Google, I suggest to use `asdf` version manager with their dotnet plugin to have multiple versions and switch between them with ease:

1. Install `asdf`: https://asdf-vm.com/guide/getting-started.html
2. Install dotnet plugin:

```
asdf plugin-add dotnet-core https://github.com/emersonsoares/asdf-dotnet-core.git
```

3. Install all versions that you need:

```
asdf install dotnet-core 6.0.403
asdf install dotnet-core 7.0.100
```

4. Choose one as a global, you may also chose another version as a local inside your project folder:

```
asdf global dotnet-core 7.0.100
cd git/project
asdf local dotnet-core 6.0.403
```

5. Check it out!

```
$ cd git/project
$ dotnet --version
6.0.403

$ cd ~
$ dotnet --version
7.0.100
```

Checkout full installation instruction on the plugin page (also, consider giving it a star!): https://github.com/emersonsoares/asdf-dotnet-core

You can manage versions of many other development tools the same way with `asdf`. Check out their docs.

Answer (score 2):

There a cask available for dotnet core 3 preview, you can install the latest preview using the following command

```
$ brew cask install dotnet-sdk-preview
```

After installation, you can see

```
$ dotnet --info 

dotnet --info
.NET Core SDK (reflecting any global.json):
 Version:   3.0.100-preview5-011568
 Commit:    b487ff10aa

Runtime Environment:
 OS Name:     Mac OS X
 OS Version:  10.14
 OS Platform: Darwin
 RID:         osx.10.14-x64
 Base Path:   /usr/local/share/dotnet/sdk/3.0.100-preview5-011568/

Host (useful for support):
  Version: 3.0.0-preview5-27626-15
  Commit:  61f30f5a23

.NET Core SDKs installed:
  2.1.403 [/usr/local/share/dotnet/sdk]
  2.2.101 [/usr/local/share/dotnet/sdk]
  2.2.102 [/usr/local/share/dotnet/sdk]
  3.0.100-preview5-011568 [/usr/local/share/dotnet/sdk]

.NET Core runtimes installed:
  Microsoft.AspNetCore.All 2.1.5 [/usr/local/share/dotnet/shared/Microsoft.AspNetCore.All]
  Microsoft.AspNetCore.All 2.2.0 [/usr/local/share/dotnet/shared/Microsoft.AspNetCore.All]
  Microsoft.AspNetCore.All 2.2.1 [/usr/local/share/dotnet/shared/Microsoft.AspNetCore.All]
  Microsoft.AspNetCore.App 2.1.5 [/usr/local/share/dotnet/shared/Microsoft.AspNetCore.App]
  Microsoft.AspNetCore.App 2.2.0 [/usr/local/share/dotnet/shared/Microsoft.AspNetCore.App]
  Microsoft.AspNetCore.App 2.2.1 [/usr/local/share/dotnet/shared/Microsoft.AspNetCore.App]
  Microsoft.AspNetCore.App 3.0.0-preview5-19227-01 [/usr/local/share/dotnet/shared/Microsoft.AspNetCore.App]
  Microsoft.NETCore.App 2.1.5 [/usr/local/share/dotnet/shared/Microsoft.NETCore.App]
  Microsoft.NETCore.App 2.2.0 [/usr/local/share/dotnet/shared/Microsoft.NETCore.App]
  Microsoft.NETCore.App 2.2.1 [/usr/local/share/dotnet/shared/Microsoft.NETCore.App]
  Microsoft.NETCore.App 3.0.0-preview5-27626-15 [/usr/local/share/dotnet/shared/Microsoft.NETCore.App]

To install additional .NET Core runtimes or SDKs:
  https://aka.ms/dotnet-download
```

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me:

```
brew cask install \
  https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/homebrew-cask/master/Casks/dotnet-sdk.rb
```

Answer (score 0):

At least in 2023, I couldn't find an nice Homebrew solution for quickly installing/switching between versions; I came up with this copy/paste "one-liner" based on the [official Microsoft documentation](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/install/macos#install-with-bash-automation) with a bit of sketchiness added in for convenience: *(I keep it in [this Gist](https://gist.github.com/andrewodri/9fdf9d7ed2de86566897dbc4e174a0df) in case you visit from the future and want to see if there are some updates)*

```
echo -ne "\033[0;31mdotnet-install:\033[0m Enter the .NET Core SDK channel (i.e. n.n, not n.n.n) you would like to install: " && read CHANNEL; curl -sSL https://dot.net/v1/dotnet-install.sh | bash -s -- --channel "${CHANNEL}" && grep -qxF 'export PATH=$PATH:$HOME/.dotnet' ~/.zshrc || echo 'export PATH=$PATH:$HOME/.dotnet' >> ~/.zshrc && source ~/.zshrc
```

This does the following:

- Prompt the user to enter a .NET Core SDK version to install
- Install the entered .NET Core SDK version
- Add the dotnet path to `~/.zshrc` file so that you can actually use it
- Source the `~/.zshrc` file so you can start using it

Just run `dotnet --info` to make sure everything is goo, and you be ready to rock!

**Note:** You may need to replace the `--channel n.n` switch with `--version n.n.n` if you want to install a specific version of the SDK.